# .NET compact framework and SQL Server Express 2008 R2

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce, sql-server-2008r2-express

I am having problems in picking the right collation / locale on a Windows Embedded Compact Edition 6.0 device.

I am using .NET compact framework 2.0 on said device.

I am having difficulties inserting the letters ŠĐČĆŽšđčćž in the database.
I am getting a PlatformNotSupported exception.

Available locales on the CE device does not list Croatian or anything similar.
When i pick SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as the database/table/column collation it works (in combination with the English (US) locale on the device, but i can't insert previous letters.

The same collation, using Management studio 2008, from a Windows 7 desktop PC, correctly accepts all those letters.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may have run into a .NET Compact Framework limitation. If I remember correctly, it does not support all languages. Is there a way to specify UTF8 characters in your database, or have you already tried that? I would throw something together for you, but our SQL CE project was ended once we realized all of our devices would be able to communicate directly with the main SQL server.

Comment: I'm not using SQL CE. The database is SQL express 2008. The problem is the collation and getting the compact frameworks locale to match the db collation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to duplicate this on our older SQL 2000 Server, and I would certainly hope that SQL Express 2008 has more for dealing with multilingual issues than SQL 2000.

I used the following code as my test:

```
private const string jp2code = "jp2code.net";

private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string croatianIn = "ŠĐČĆŽšđčćž";
  string croatianOut = TestCroatian(croatianIn);
  Console.WriteLine(String.Compare(croatianIn, croatianOut));
}

private string TestCroatian(string input) {
  string result = null;
  string sql = "INSERT INTO SUITEMSG (MsgFrom, [Message]) VALUES (@MsgFrom, @Message);";
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Data.Connection)) {
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MsgFrom", jp2code);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Message", input);
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
  sql = "SELECT [Message] FROM SUITEMSG WHERE MsgFrom=@MsgFrom;";
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Data.Connection)) {
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MsgFrom", jp2code);
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
  }
  return result;
}
```

Both the input and the output were identical.

Are you sure there isn't something else you are doing?

Can you update your question to post a short code example like I have done above to show what does NOT work?

Comment: Could you check the locale of your CE device? I believe that is the problem. Also, what is the collation of your db? I will give you a sample as soon as possible. I am not using parameters but writing the query in code. Will check as soon as possible.

Comment: I'm on a Windows Mobile device, but I'd have to guess that everything is still set to English; I have not changed anything as it has come out of the Mobile SDK on the device. Using the techniques found on [a blog post](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/30/sql-server-2005-find-database-collation-using-t-sql-and-ssms/), I was able to see that my server's Collation is set to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

Comment: This was the right collation that made it work `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`